# Direct image sheaf and sheaf of direct image (of divisors)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables, birational-geometry

I am reading a paper,  let $h:Z\rightarrow Y$ be a bimeromorphic morphism between normal complex varieties, so h is an isomorphic over an analytic Zariski open subset of codimension $\ge 2$ in $Y$, **the author then claims that:** for every Weil divisor $D$ on $Z$,

$$h_*\mathcal O_Z(D) \quad\text{and}\quad\mathcal O_Y(h_*D) \quad\text{are isomorphic in codimension 1.}$$

Here, $h_*D$ denotes the direct image of $D$, and $h_*\mathcal O_Z(D)$ denotes the direct image sheaf, I can't figure out why they are isomorphic in **codimension 1** rather than **codimension 2**.  In fact, I have no idea to prove it strictly...

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take the example where $h$ is blowup of a point on $\mathbb P^2$.